# Bootstrap gallery grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make custom gallery grid using bootstrap. All goes well but im stuck on last step. 
I'm posting HTML structure since i belive it's problem in here somewhere but my code cotains some css (paddings/margins mostly) and JS (explained why below).

HTML:

```
<div class="about_gallery">
  <div class="col-xs-9 pd-9">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 pd-8">
        <div class="color1"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-lTAkZcm_aO0/VoR2I2nDq8I/AAAAAAAAGIg/G0vVuMw1nrI/s1600/NEW-YEARS-RESOLUTIONS-calendar.jpg"/></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 pd-4">
        <div class="color2"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTj4NOe5Usd1_GJv4waOL5JbnJFVEGeduUHlB3Ej-TIpUhqVEouLw"/></div>
      </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 pd-4">
        <div class="color3"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7c/7e/41/7c7e41ad177113fecc68a0213cf724c2.jpg"/></div>
          <div class="color11"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTj4NOe5Usd1_GJv4waOL5JbnJFVEGeduUHlB3Ej-TIpUhqVEouLw"/></div>         

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 pd-8">
        <div class="color4"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-lTAkZcm_aO0/VoR2I2nDq8I/AAAAAAAAGIg/G0vVuMw1nrI/s1600/NEW-YEARS-RESOLUTIONS-calendar.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 cl-5">
              <div class="color5"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTj4NOe5Usd1_GJv4waOL5JbnJFVEGeduUHlB3Ej-TIpUhqVEouLw"/></div>
              <div class="color12"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTj4NOe5Usd1_GJv4waOL5JbnJFVEGeduUHlB3Ej-TIpUhqVEouLw"/></div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 cl-6">
              <div class="color6"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7c/7e/41/7c7e41ad177113fecc68a0213cf724c2.jpg"/></div>
            </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-3 pd-3">
      <div class="color8 "><img class="pion-rect" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7c/7e/41/7c7e41ad177113fecc68a0213cf724c2.jpg"/></div>
      <div class="color9"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTj4NOe5Usd1_GJv4waOL5JbnJFVEGeduUHlB3Ej-TIpUhqVEouLw"/></div>
      <div class="color10"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTj4NOe5Usd1_GJv4waOL5JbnJFVEGeduUHlB3Ej-TIpUhqVEouLw"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y6co8e5u/

The goal is to have grid like here: [Grid example](https://s11.postimg.org/u2nbjzvkj/oznaczenia_galeria.jpg)

As you can see on bottom left corner instead of 1 horizontal rectangle i have two squares and i don't know how to "connect" them since it's in different columns. It's my first time with bootstrap so it's probably a little bit messy. (I'm also not sure if my JS is needed here but when i added spaces between pictures i needed to extend the pictures) I'm open for any other solution too.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I guess this could be replicated by abusing Bootstrap's grid system, but I don't think this was ever the intention of that system -- keywords from a book I learned Bootstrap in, "...not for tetris-like grids."

Comment: Any idea how to create it without bootstrap?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you are trying to add the `.color7` div, append it to `<div class="col-xs-4 pd-4">`, just after the `.color3` block. The block will look like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 pd-4">
    <div class="color3"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/7c/7e/41/7c7e41ad177113fecc68a0213cf724c2.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="color7"><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-lTAkZcm_aO0/VoR2I2nDq8I/AAAAAAAAGIg/G0vVuMw1nrI/s1600/NEW-YEARS-RESOLUTIONS-calendar.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

then on the css, set `.color7 {width: calc(200% + 10px);}`

here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y6co8e5u/3/

no change to the js code.

Comment: Thanks ! that's exactly what i needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to **restructure** your HTML a bit, have to put

```
<div class="color10"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTj4NOe5Usd1_GJv4waOL5JbnJFVEGeduUHlB3Ej-TIpUhqVEouLw"/></div>
```

inside the  `<div class="col-xs-4 pd-4">`

of second row. Hope this is what you want.
Check updated jsfiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/mayankN/y6co8e5u/1/

Comment: Interesting, what's that jQuery usage?

Comment: yes, but modification is done in html part only, no script change.

Comment: Thanks for answer :) but i meant horizontal rectangle not vertical. @phobia82 got correct answer! Thanks again